# Change permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

I changed the permalink structure from `/%category%/%postname%/` to `/%category%/%post_id%/`

What url should I put in the .htaccess file?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to put anything in the htaccess file. Is something not working?

Comment: Yes 404 arrived  exemple : https://www.bricolage.fr/outillage-electroportatif/scies-circulaires/mini-scie-circulaire-teccpo-professionnelle-scie-circulaire-480w-lame-de-scie-diametre-115mm-moteur-en-fil-de-cuivre-pur-angle-de-coupe-reglable-de-90-a-45-tams25p-10ecode-hkaavbo/

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the url structure to end with the post id, not the post name so your reference link will go to a 404. That's correct behaviour. If you look at the URLs of the pages in your right-hand menu you will see they end in a number, not a name: https://www.bricolage.fr/outillage-electroportatif/scies-circulaires/4023/ 
If you want to redirect the post name url to the post id url you should install a redirect plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I do not want 404 error, my configuration is good yes, but is old address, I do not want that.
I can not redirect them 1 to 1 I have more than 1000..It is necessary to modify the file so that it puts in place the new structure as on my post 1 but I do not know what is the command line. .